# dplyr::mutate_at() relying on multiple columns with a given prefix/suffix

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr::mutate_at() can be used to apply the same function to multiple columns. It also allows you to set the results in new columns using a named list.

However, what if I have many columns in pairs (say, `data1_a`, `data1_b`, `data2_a`, `data2_b`, ...) and I want to multiply those pairs together? Is that possible?

By hand, that would look like

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
})

data.frame(data1_a = 1:3, data1_b = 2:4,
           data2_a = 3:5, data2_b = 4:6) %>%
  mutate(
    data1 = data1_a * data1_b,
    data2 = data2_a * data2_b
  )
#>   data1_a data1_b data2_a data2_b data1 data2
#> 1       1       2       3       4     2    12
#> 2       2       3       4       5     6    20
#> 3       3       4       5       6    12    30
```

My current solution is to write a function which takes the unsuffixed variable name (i.e. `"data1"`), creates the suffixed names and then performs a simple `mutate()` on that variable using `get()`. I then call that function for each output:

```
foo <- function(df, name) {
  a <- paste0(name, "_a")
  b <- paste0(name, "_b")

  return(
    mutate(
      df,
      !!name := get(a) * get(b)
    )
  )
}

data.frame(data1_a = 1:3, data1_b = 2:4,
           data2_a = 3:5, data2_b = 4:6) %>%
  foo("data1") %>%
  foo("data2")
#>   data1_a data1_b data2_a data2_b data1 data2
#> 1       1       2       3       4     2    12
#> 2       2       3       4       5     6    20
#> 3       3       4       5       6    12    30
```

(or write a loop over all the variable names if there were more of them)

But if it's possible to use `mutate_at` or something of the sort, that'd be much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adopting @akrun's elegant solution, I noticed it was unfortunately very inefficient (since it has to recreate two dataframes), taking almost a second on a dataset with 20,000 rows and 11 "groups".

So a while ago I developed the following function (with a bit of help from [@user12728748](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60680179/2175231)... sorry for not posting here sooner), which takes the names of the groups ("data1", "data2", etc) and a formula using the prefixes, allowing for `bquote`-style quoting for constant names:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

mutateSet <- function(df, colNames, formula,
                      isPrefix = TRUE,
                      separator = "_") {
  vars <- all.vars(formula)

  # extracts names wrapped in `.()`
  escapedNames <- function (expr)
  {
    unquote <- function(e) {
      if (is.pairlist(e) || length(e) <= 1L) NULL
      else if (e[[1L]] == as.name("."))      deparse(e[[2L]])
      else                                   unlist(sapply(e, unquote))
    }
    unquote(substitute(expr))
  }

  escapedVars <- eval(rlang::expr(escapedNames(!!formula)))

  # remove escaped names from mapping variables
  vars <- setdiff(vars, escapedVars)

  # get output prefix/suffix as string
  lhs <- rlang::f_lhs(formula) %>%
    all.vars()

  # get operation as string
  # deparse() can have line breaks; paste0() brings it back to one line
  rhs <- rlang::f_rhs(formula) %>%
    deparse() %>%
    paste0(collapse = "")

  # dummy function to cover for bquote escaping
  . <- function(x) x

  for (i in colNames) {
    if (isPrefix) {
      aliases <- paste0(vars, separator, i)
      newCol  <- paste0(lhs,  separator, i)
    } else {
      aliases <- paste0(i, separator, vars)
      newCol  <- paste0(i, separator, lhs)
    }

    if (length(lhs) == 0) newCol <- i

    mapping <- rlang::list2(!!!aliases)
    names(mapping) <- vars
    mapping <- do.call(wrapr::qc, mapping)

    df <- rlang::expr(wrapr::let(
      mapping,
      df %>% dplyr::mutate(!!newCol := ...RHS...)
    )) %>%
      deparse() %>%
      gsub(
        pattern = "...RHS...",
        replacement = rhs
      ) %>%
      {eval(parse(text = .))}
  }

  return(df)
}

df <- data.frame(a_data1 = 1:3, b_data1 = 2:4,
                a_data2 = 3:5, b_data2 = 4:6,
                static = 5:7)

mutateSet(df, "data1", ~ a + b)
#>   a_data1 b_data1 a_data2 b_data2 static data1
#> 1       1       2       3       4      5     3
#> 2       2       3       4       5      6     5
#> 3       3       4       5       6      7     7
mutateSet(df, c("data1", "data2"), x ~ sqrt(a) + b)
#>   a_data1 b_data1 a_data2 b_data2 static  x_data1  x_data2
#> 1       1       2       3       4      5 3.000000 5.732051
#> 2       2       3       4       5      6 4.414214 7.000000
#> 3       3       4       5       6      7 5.732051 8.236068
mutateSet(df, c("data1", "data2"), ~ a + b + .(static))
#>   a_data1 b_data1 a_data2 b_data2 static data1 data2
#> 1       1       2       3       4      5     8    12
#> 2       2       3       4       5      6    11    15
#> 3       3       4       5       6      7    14    18
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This can probably be cleaned up (especially that heinous for-loop), but it works for now.

Repeating @user12728748's performance test, we see this is ~100x faster:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    invisible(lapply(c("dplyr", "tidyr", "rlang", "wrapr", "microbenchmark"),
                     require, character.only = TRUE))
})

polymutate <- function(df, formula) {
    form <- rlang::f_rhs(formula)

    df %>% 
        mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c('.value', 'grp'),
                     names_sep = "_") %>%
        group_by(grp) %>%
        transmute(rn, new = eval(form)) %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = new) %>%
        select(-rn) %>%
        bind_cols(df, .)
}

set.seed(1)                 
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(sample(1:12, 6E6, replace=TRUE), ncol=6)),
               c("a_data1", "b_data1", "a_data2", "b_data2", "a_data3", "b_data3"))

pd <- polymutate(df, ~ a + b)
pd2 <- mutateSet(df, c("data1", "data2", "data3"), ~ a + b)

all.equal(pd, pd2)
#> [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(polymutate(df, ~ a + b), 
               mutateSet(df, c("data1", "data2", "data3"), ~ a + b),
               times=10L)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>        expr      min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
#>  polymutate 1612.306 1628.9776 1690.78586 1670.15600 1741.3490 1806.1412    10
#>  mutateSet     8.757    9.6302   13.27135   10.45965   19.2976   20.4657    10
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `pivot_longer/pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c('grp', '.value'),
        names_sep = "_") %>% 
    group_by(grp) %>%
    transmute(rn, new = a * b) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = new) %>%
    select(-rn) %>%
    bind_cols(df1, .)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  data1_a data1_b data2_a data2_b data1 data2
#    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <int> <int>
#1       1       2       3       4     2    12
#2       2       3       4       5     6    20
#3       3       4       5       6    12    30
```

---

Or another option is to `split` into a `list` based on the column names and then do the `*`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   split.default(str_remove(names(.), "_.*")) %>% 
   map_dfr(reduce, `*`) %>%
   bind_cols(df1, .)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  data1_a data1_b data2_a data2_b data1 data2
#    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <int> <int>
#1       1       2       3       4     2    12
#2       2       3       4       5     6    20
#3       3       4       5       6    12    30
```

---

With `mutate`, it is possible, but it would be more manual

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(data1 = select(., starts_with('data1')) %>%
                reduce(`*`),
         data2 = select(., starts_with('data2')) %>%
                reduce(`*`))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(data1_a = 1:3, data1_b = 2:4,
           data2_a = 3:5, data2_b = 4:6)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible using the [`cur_column()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html) function within [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html).

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
  data1_a = 1:3,
  data1_b = 2:4,
  data2_a = 3:5, 
  data2_b = 4:6
  )

mutate(
  dat,
  across(ends_with("a"), ~ . * dat[[str_replace(cur_column(), "a$", "b")]],
         .names = "updated_{col}")
  )
```

Returns:

```
  data1_a data1_b data2_a data2_b updated_data1_a updated_data2_a
1       1       2       3       4               2              12
2       2       3       4       5               6              20
3       3       4       5       6              12              30
```

Where `updated_data1_a` and `updated_data2_a` contain the desired output variables.